# NSTask environment variables in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift, nstask

How can I set an environment variable for my application in swift? Using the editor schema It works only while running with xcode but not in the compiled application of course.

I already tryed to do:

```
let environment: NSDictionary = ["launched" : true]
task.environment = environment
```

but in this way the launcher that I'm going to execute with NSTask will crash (this doesn't happen when I use the editor schema for setting the variable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grab the `environment` dictionary from `NSProcessInfo` & add your variables to that.

Sounds like the child process needs one of the standard variables like `HOME` or `PATH`.